# Canonical Json Path for a node

Tags: java, jsonpath

Unlike Json Pointer, there isn't a single Json Path for a given node; in this document, the node could be accessed by `$.foo`, `$['foo']`, or even `$['\u0066oo']`.

```
{
    "foo": 10
}
```

The reference js implementation supports outputting matching paths and uses array notation `[]` for all properties. It doesn't handle escaping correctly and just pastes the property name in single quotes.

The Java Jayway implementation does the same.

I'm leaning towards the canonical form being array notation, single quotes, and json-like escaping for control characters, *single* quotes, and backslashes, but I can't find an actual definition. Did I miss something?